# can anybody help me with Login form PHP with HTML?

Tags: php, html, authentication, passwords

I'm having a bit of trouble integrating my PHP code into my HTML code! Can anybody help or point me in the right direction?

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <h2>Enter Username and Password</h2> 
  <div class = "container form-signin">
     
    
  </div> <!-- /container -->
  
  <div class = "container">
  
     <form class = "form-signin" role = "form" 
        action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
        ?>" method = "post">
        <h4 class = "form-signin-heading"><?php echo $msg; ?></h4>
        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
           name = "username" placeholder = "username = tutorialspoint" 
           required autofocus></br>
        <input type = "password" class = "form-control"
           name = "password" placeholder = "password = 1234" required>
        <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type = "submit" 
           name = "login">Login</button>
           
     </form>
            
     Click here to clean <a href = "logout.php" tite = "Logout">Session.
     
     
  </div>
```

My PHP code is

```
 <?php
        $msg = '';
        
        if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
           && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
            
           if ($_POST['username'] == 'tutorialspoint' && 
              $_POST['password'] == '1234') {
              $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
              $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
              $_SESSION['username'] = 'tutorialspoint';
              
              echo 'You have entered valid use name and password';
           }else {
              $msg = 'Wrong username or password';
           }
        }
     ?>
```

I would like to please make a login user as written
And then allow him access only that the logged in can authorize this page.

Comment: I did not quite understand what you want. But are you saying that you need to make a login page where anyone can use it? If you want to do so, you need to use a database, such as MySQL and MSSQLServer.

Comment: Sure about `tite = "Logout"`?

Comment: The title of your question is not very "searchable" for people who may need the same support in the future.  When you isolate where your problem is, please try to use greater specificity in your question title.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create a login system you will need to have a database (e.g. MySQL) which you will automatically get when you install a localhost server like WAMP / XAMPP

After that you have got your database and the tables set up will need to connect that database to your application usually we create a file named config.php or whatever and write the code to connect to the database.

After connecting you will then will be able to develop your login and register system.

On your login page you will call this file and then write a query to fetch all the records which are stored in the database and specifically look for values of the username and password entered by the user in the login form. If the passed parameters are matched then you redirect the user to the page you want them to be (On redirected see **header redirect articles**)

If passed parameters are not matched then can display a custom error message to the user

For logging in and providing access to users who are only logged see the tutorials on SESSIONS

Refer this tutorial - [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCo6JqGMi30)

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple login, everything is right. but you must call `session_start()` function before using `$_SESSION` variable in your code (in login page or in another pages). absolutely for a real login page you need to connect to database and more ...

```
<?php
    $msg = '';

    if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        if ($_POST['username'] == 'tutorialspoint' && $_POST['password'] == '1234') {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
            $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
            $_SESSION['username'] = 'tutorialspoint';

            echo 'You have entered valid use name and password';
        }else {
            $msg = 'Wrong username or password';
        }
    }
?>
```